# Performance issues after upgrading to Capybara Webkit 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

We are currently upgrading our Rails 3.2 (Ruby 2, Mongoid 3.1.5) App to Capybara Webkit 1.0.0 from 0.13.1. After the gem upgrade we fixed all new failing specs to comply with Capybara 2's new features and (default) settings. That went quite well. BUT: Our whole test suite is now significantly slower than before (~21 minutes compared to ~12 minutes).

Some tests take about 20 seconds. After lots of debugging we figgured out that the issue is not in those slow tests themselves (they run in 2 seconds as single test or in a selected group) but in the cumulation of several tests. We do run (and test) ajax calls in most of these feature tests. So the guess is that the webkit server gets blocked after some tests. But we didn't have that problem with the old capybara version.

I now, every test suite is quite individual so I don't ask for specifics. I'm happy with any idea which can lead to a solution.

Has anyone experienced (and solved ;-) similar problems? Maybe any ideas I didn't have yet?

Answer (score 0):

Clue: Check for the number of files the webkit server opens and webkit processes during the test run

```
 lsof |grep webkit
```